# Elasticsearch: searching with symbol $

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I create the query

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/liza_index/.percolator/UNIQ_ID20' -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"regexp" : {"message" : "50"}}}}'
```

And try to find the matches in the text "it costs about $50 now":

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/liza_index/liza_type/_percolate' -d '{"doc" : {"message" : "it costs about $50 now"}}'
```

When there is no spaces between the '50' and '$' the query doesn't work. But when there is a space, it works. Though after the tokenizing the text looks like

```
{
"tokens": [{
    "token": "it",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 2,
    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position": 0
}, {
    "token": "costs",
    "start_offset": 3,
    "end_offset": 8,
    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position": 1
}, {
    "token": "about",
    "start_offset": 9,
    "end_offset": 14,
    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position": 2
}, {
    "token": "50",
    "start_offset": 16,
    "end_offset": 18,
    "type": "<NUM>",
    "position": 3
}, {
    "token": "now",
    "start_offset": 19,
    "end_offset": 22,
    "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position": 4
}]}
```

in both cases.

Why can't I find the '50' written together with '$'? How can I do it?

Comment: can you post the mapping for `message` field ? also is the percolate query you posted valid  i.e  `regexp` option in `match` query does not make sense

Comment: also is the analyze output in OP is it obtained using the following `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/liza_index/_analyze?field=message&text=it%20costs%20about%20%2450%20now"`  ? if not could you paste the result of the following ?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, the query was `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/liza_index/.percolator/UNIQ_ID20' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"minimum_should_match":1,"should":{"span_or":{"clauses":[{"span_multi":{"match":{"regexp":{"message":"50"}}}}]}}}}}'`
But my query to the tokenizer was wrong from very beginning: I made it without the "field=message" and got the wrong result - at the truth the token with the "$" looked like "$50". So, I edit the module which creates queries to the elasticsearch and it helps. Thanks!

Comment: So, could you tell me, why with the  settings `"tokenizer": {"liza_tokenizer": {"type": "pattern", "pattern": "(\.\s*)|[\s,\[\]\(\)\"\!\?\`\*\;\:\/<>«»\#]+", "flags": "UNICODE_CASE"}}` and the query `http://localhost:9200/liza_index/_analyze?field=message&text=costs%20#50%20now&tokenizer=liza_tokenizer` I get only one token - "costs", not 3 ones - "costs", "50" and "now"?

Comment: `#` needs to be url-encoded it should be  : `http://localhost:9200/liza_index/_analyze?field=message&text=costs%20%2350%20now&‌​tokenizer=liza_tokenizer`

Comment: also based on the comments the `liza_tokenizer` is missing `$` in the pattern as a result it is not tokenizing `50$` to `50`

Comment: Now it's clear. Thanks!